# Motor shield and Arduino Led not turning on when connected to laptop and Arduino is heating up

Tags: arduino-uno

I have a problem like that....As I connect my Arduino to the laptop with the usb cable and the motor shield connected, my led won't turn on neither does the led on the Arduino. And the small chip like thingy beside the usb cable also heats up really bad...please help!

Comment: disconnect the motor shield

Comment: Is a motor connected?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://cdn.instructables.com/F9N/DXWA/JNZ4CAF7/F9NDXWAJNZ4CAF7.LARGE.jpg) component gets hot?

Comment: There's not much information to go on here. If nothing is lighting up at *all* there's a problem. Disconnect everything and see if the Arduino works at all.

Answer (score 1):

0

You might have burned one of the onboard voltage regulators. In my case, it was AMS1117 which was burned and my Arduino was behaving similarly. You will notice that the Arduino will work with an external power supply connected to the Vin pin of Arduino and it will not become hot. 

 In short, the small chip which is getting hot is a voltage regulator may be AMS1117 and you have to replace it manually or buy a new Arduino